# First seen in a conda install ... proc=*=cpus ... -- What does this equal asterisk equal (=*=) syntax mean?

Tags: python, bash, syntax, operators, conda

While installing a conda package, I noted this =*= syntax, however upon google searching and checking SO, I am unable to find an explanation as to what is happening here.

```
conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c numba -c conda-forge \
    ucx-proc=*=gpu \ #HERE
    ucx ucx-py cudatoolkit=10.1
```

Normally I have seen the use of an equal sign to install a specific version, like cudatoolkit=10.1, but I have not been able to infer what =*=gpu could mean.

Comment: the full syntax for a package is `pkg-name=version=build-string`. `*` is a wildcard for version, so it means in words: install any version of the package ucx-proc with the build-string `gpu`.

Comment: we did this as a mechanism to help users install ucx builds with or without cuda.  moving foward we'd like to remove this need.  ucx-proc, acts a a constraints for the ucx package: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#run-constrained 
https://github.com/rapidsai/ucx-split-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml

Answer (score 0):

To coalesce the comments and answer your question directly, it is saying

"install the package named `ucx-proc` with 'whatever version' and with `gpu` build-string."

As @cel, mentioned, the syntax is `pkg-name=version=build-string`.